# Load asynchronously javascript function

Tags: javascript, extjs3

I have a function `constGrid(arg1)` to be called 3 times to build extjs grid when form loads. My page has other fields also. what is really want is how should i call the constGrid method so that my page does not wait for them to load and does not hang till the method completion.

`onLoad(function() {
    for (var i=0; i<arg.length;i++) {
        constGrid(arg[i]);
    }
    ....
})`

But when i use setTimeout like below the webpage especially IE hangs till completion.

`onLoad(function() {
    for (var i=0; i <argArr.length;i++) {
        (function(i) {
           setTimeout(constGrid(argArr[i]));
        })(i));
    }
    .... 
})`

Your help in making this asynchronous will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to add the timeout value (millisecond) as well, it's required argument: `window.setTimeout("function",milliseconds);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this works in other browsers to be honest. What you need to pass to setTimeout is a function. What you are actually passing it is the result of a function.

Try this instead (untested though):

`onLoad(function() {
    for (var i=0; i <argArr.length;i++) {
        setTimeout(constGrid.bind(window, argArr[i]));
    }
    .... 
})`

This is assuming `consGrid` is in global scope, which it seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you invoke 'constGrid' already where it should just be passed as argument to setTimeout. Define a function instead:

```
setTimeout(function() {constGrid(argArr[i]);}, 0);
```

(0 ms i.o to do it immediately but async)